# android setOnClickListener multiple buttons at once

Tags: android, onlongclicklistener

I have three buttons with ids b00, b01, b02 that I want to all do the same thing when they are long clicked. Is there a better way to do this than

```
b00.setOnLongClickListener {
        //code
         true
}

b01.setOnLongClickListener {
         //same code
         true
}

b02.setOnLongClickListener {
        //same code
        true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
    /...

    b00.setOnLongClickListener(this)
    b01.setOnLongClickListener(this)
    b02.setOnLongClickListener(this)
}

//...

override fun onLongClick(v: View?): Boolean {
    var id = v?.id
    if ((id == b00.id) or (id == b01.id) or (id == b02.id)) {
        //your code
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: I like this idea but it is telling me that the override is not overriding anything. Also that it doesn't like the this as a parameter

Comment: @Edward Make sure you implemented `View.OnLongClickListener`

Comment: I'm sure this is really obvious but how would you do that

Comment: @Edward `class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnLongClickListener{}`

Answer (score 0):

Following your example, I assume you're using Kotlin.

In programming, try to keep it simple, easy to understand and don't repeat yourself.

Since for `OnLongClickListener` you need to return `Boolean` that you consumed event, I suggest adding [inline](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html) function

```
inline fun consumeEvent(function: () -> Unit): Boolean {
    function()
    return true
}
```

Then, move common code from listeners to new function, like `fun myFunction()` and call it.

```
fun myFunction() {
    // some code
}

b00.setOnLongClickListener { consumeEvent { myFunction() } }
b01.setOnLongClickListener { consumeEvent { myFunction() } }
b02.setOnLongClickListener { consumeEvent { myFunction() } }
```